# Clicking on element by finding it first by column and row

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I'm trying to click on element in table that is only seperated by columns and every colum only has one row.
The table looks like this
[image]

I tried locating element like this

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f"//div[@class='srb-ParticipantLabelCentered gl-Market_General-cn1 ' and contains(., '140.0')]/following::span[text() ='2.40']"))).click()
```

but instead of clicking on row that contains "2.40" and is next to 140.0 it clicks on row 2.40 that is next to 131.0.
It clicks on first element that matches value "2.40".
How could I make it so it clicks on 2.40 that is next to 140.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have two similar `div` elements with same `class name` and `text` value.

If so use `last()` option in `xpath` to get the `last one`, which should identify the expected element.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//div[@class='srb-ParticipantLabelCentered gl-Market_General-cn1 ' and contains(., '140.0')])[last()]/following::span[text() ='2.40']"))).click()
```

This will work on both cases. If only one element or more than one elements.

Comment: Why are you using `f` with the XPath eexpression? I see no parameters passed there, no formatting performed.

Comment: @Prophet, Just typo. Copied  from question :(

Comment: Thanks it partially worked, but now the problem is when value 2.40 is not the last element,  it ends up clicking on wrong element.

Comment: @JakeM, If the page is dynamic and without page url it become very difficult to provide correct solution. we can trial and error only!

Comment: @KunduK Link : https://www.365sport365.com/#/AC/B18/C20841922/D19/E16178163/F19/I1/ , under Alternative Game Total

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are only 2 occurrence of **2.40**, you can try the below XPath:

`(//*[contains(text(),'2.40')])[2]`

Explanation: searches all the nodes(`//*`) which contains text `2.40` and fetches the second occurrence(`[2]`)